# MFC OnDraw vs. OnPaint

Tags: mfc, ondraw, onpaint, wm-paint

I am wondering about the difference between `OnDraw()` and `OnPaint()` in MFC.

After searching the Internet for a while, I found a useful [article](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?327604-RESOLVED-OnDraw()-vs-OnPaint()). In summary,

1. `WM_PAINT` will trigger `OnPaint()`, which calls `OnDraw()` and passes a `CDC*`:

   ```cpp
   void CView::OnPaint()
   {
       // standard paint routine
       CPaintDC dc(this);
       OnPrepareDC(&dc);
       OnDraw(&dc);
   }
   ```
2. Another [article](http://computer-programming-forum.com/82-mfc/c54806a1479b95b0.htm) mentions that when printing a document, `OnPrint()` also calls `OnDraw()` by passing a printer DC.  Therefore, by overriding `OnDraw()`, you get screen painting and printing both in one function, which is convenient.

I tried to put my statements for drawing in either `OnDraw()` and `OnPaint()`. Either can work well. `OnDraw()` is a little easier because it has already gotten a pointer `pDC`.

Comment: `OnPaint` is a method of `CPluginWindow`. `OnDraw` is a method in the class `CView` and is more general. `CPluginWindow` inherits `CView`.

Comment: @user51187286016 `OnPaint` is a message-handling routine in the [`CWnd` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170#onpaint), which is the base class from which (almost) all other MFC windows and view types are derived.

Answer (score 4):

[Device contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-contexts) are an ancient abstraction. They have been described as early as 1982 in the first edition of [Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Graphics:_Principles_and_Practice) (probably even earlier) and seem to confuse people to this day.

The primary purpose of a device context is to abstract peculiarities of render devices (such as displays, printers, in-memory bitmaps, etc.) and provide a coherent interface. Code that's rendering into a device context generally does not need to know, which device is ultimately consuming the render commands.

The documentation entry titled [Drawing in a View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/drawing-in-a-view) goes on to explain how the system is intended to work: In short, all painting should be performed in an `OnDraw` override that receives a device context. The system-provided `OnPaint` implementation then constructs a `CPaintDC` and calls `OnDraw`.

Up to this point this seems to be just an overly complex way to render the contents of a window. Things start to make sense when you implement, say, printing support. Now all you have to do is set up a printing device context and call `OnDraw`. Nothing in your `OnDraw` implementation needs to change.